# Why does Chrome 35 disconnect after running my Karma tests?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, karma-runner

I have a Karma test suite that runs great in Firefox and Chrome 34. Chrome auto-upgraded to 35 and I'm getting this error after the tests have run:

> WARN [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Disconnected (1 times),
>   because no message in 10000 ms.
>
> Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.2): Executed 712 of 712 DISCONNECTED
>   (14.836 secs / 5.021 secs)

The tests all run and pass, but Chrome disconnecting causes the suite to fail.

We're running our tests from Grunt on OS X Mavericks.

Here's our config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    port: 9876,
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    basePath: 'app/build',
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: [
      'Chrome',
      'Firefox'
    ],
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-story-reporter',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],
    files: [
      // lots of files
    ],
    exclude: [
      '**/*.scenario.js'
    ],
    reporters: ['coverage', 'dots'],
    preprocessors: {
      '!(bower_components)/**/!(*.spec).js': 'coverage'
    },
    coverageReporter:  {
      type: 'cobertura',
      dir: '../coverage',
      file: 'coverage.xml'
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem and its driving me crazy!

Comment: I have seen test suites for other projects which work correctly in Chrome 35 and 36, so I think this might be an issue with our particular test suite. I suspect an asynchronous process is somehow preventing Chrome from exiting correctly.

Comment: Yeah I think it must just be something in my environment. Moved over to use phantomJS for now. thanks for the update!

Answer (score 12):

Please add a browserNoActivityTimeout in your karma.conf.js file. It is 10000 msec by default.  I had a similar issue. Chrome seems to be taking some time to load and notify karma. I increased the timeout to 30000 and that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added `browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000` to our config, but got the same result. `WARN [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.3)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 30000 ms.
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.3): Executed 714 of 714 DISCONNECTED (33.361 secs / 3.561 secs)`

Comment: Not sure on how much timeout you may need to set. Try to play around with it and see what happens.

Comment: Chrome isn't doing anything. I'm not sure it's a timeout issue.